# how to create sliding messages up

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, message, slideup

How can I create the sliding messages that goes upwards, as in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihGpn.png)?

That when you create a new message the old one will slide up. I tried to do with slideup, but it does not work for me.

And that belong there, the messages for close with button in the corner after
I'm just interested in knowing how to make them slide, to close the messages

```
<div id="Message"></div>
   <button id="button">add message</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $("#button").click(function(){
          $("#Message").append('<div>messages</div>').slideUp('slow');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#button" ).click( function () {

    $( "#Message" ).animate({ scrollTop: $( this ).height () }, 1000 );

});
```

But doing like this only pushes message up when you send message, what if there are other notification in message box like user is active notify ?  You need to have something that checks if any changes in the Message div are made, then pushes it up.

Comment: I've tried with the code but, I do not work, or I have not managed to make it work. Thanks for this answer.

I consider that I have to take into account your suggestion to verify if there is a message to move it up, I just do not know that how to implement it seems to me that I have to study a little to find a solution Thanks

Comment: try it, my simple codepen to demostrate doing scroll have never been so easy :D [ https://codepen.io/ShadowLegend/pen/QOWZRP ]

Comment: thank you, I think that with this link you can give me an idea of how to implement it, 
I appreciate the help, if I have the code good, I will publish it so that more people see  and can benefit from the. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you're trying to develop something that already exists in some capacity in the real world, it's better to first check if there already exists a jQuery plugin or library that does what you ask for.

https://jqueryhouse.com/jquery-chat-plugins/

Give these a shot.

Comment: The truth if there are plugins that do that but right now I want to know how to do that kind of animation.  there are people who will not know how to implement those plugins and consider 
hard, the easy  itsthat so they could see the code here and see how they work and help others learn how things work. Thanks for for this answer.